# Keep field Position on PodioAppField::update

Tags: php, podio

I am following the documentation https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications and the given models from the SDK.

I'm adding a new app to an existing app reference like so:

```
$attributes = array( 
        "referenced_apps" => array(ref_app_id1 , ref_app_id2)                        
    );

PodioAppField::update( 123 ,  'field_id' ,array (
                                                "settings" => $attributes
                                           ));
```

My problem is now, that the field was formerly on position 2 while I've had a calculation field on position 1.
After updating the app the positions have switched.

Is it possible to keep the field on its origin position without adding the preceding fields to the update? - Or do I have to repeat the preceding calculations etc?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can keep the current position using the attribute delta in addition to settings. The best method will be

```
$existing_field_config = PodioAppField::get( $app_id, $field_id )->config;
```

Then add the new attribute to the existing config variable, so that other field configurations remains the same.

```
$existing_field_config['settings']['referenced_apps'] = array(ref_app_id1 , ref_app_id2);
PodioAppField::update( 123 ,  'field_id' ,array (
                                            "settings" => $existing_field_config
                                       ));
```